# Filemaker Pro advanced Set field, perform find.

Tags: filemaker

Im writing a script to find records. Since some of my find criteria is in global fields etc... Im

going to layout
Enter find mode
set fields

thats no problem, but I need to set a field that has multiple criteria, like or..I tried a few things but not nailing it. Something like below is what I need. I need Out date records with the >= global start date or null

Set Field [table::OutDate; ">=" & global::G_Start or "="

any help is appreciated..

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: I need to perform the find with 2 variables in a single field. A date field >= global date or null. needs to be selected. I can do them 1 at a time, but not at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A date field >= global date or null.

An OR find requires two (or more) find requests. If you're scripting this, then do:

```
Enter Find Mode[]
Set Field [ table::OutDate ; ">=" & global::G_Start ]
New Record/Request
Set Field [ table::OutDate ; "=" ]
Perform Find[]
```

**Note**: there's no need to set any variables - global fields remain accessible in Find mode.

Comment: thats it...exactly what I need. Thanks much. Now knowing I can New Record/Request in find mode answers a lot of unknown hair pulling questions. haha.. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are after, but I would set variables based on your global fields, to avoid any ambiguity. Then it seems you are trying to enter multiple find requests. When you enter find mode, you can set the field for the first request:

Set Field [table::OutDate; ">=" & $gstart ]

and then add a new request, and enter your next request:

Set Field [table::OutDate; "=" ]

It may help to perform the find you want manually, entering multiple find requests, so you know how to expect it will behave in your script.

Hope this helps
Mike

Comment: Can I enter a new request in a script before the perform find? this might be the missing piece to the puzzle in my brain. I can do the find I need manually and it works as I think it should. but since Im using global dates I need to script it out.